# How to pass arrays and parameter with method post from Jquery

Tags: javascript

I try to pass a set of parameters and array with the method post with JQuery of one documment to other, but this not works. I make the next:

```
var datos_contrato = ["1","2"];
$.post("<?=Zend_Registry::get('base_action')?>insert.php", {
            pos: a_pos, cre: a_cre, cep: a_cep, 'ddc': datos_contrato
......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify(datos_contrato)` to convert the array to a string, and then in PHP convert it back to an array with `$datos_contrato = json_decode($_POST['ddc'])`.